# merge ngClass attributes when replace true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my directive which has `replace: true` set on directive definition

```
<my-custom-tag>
</my-custom-tag>
```

this is the directive template

```
<div data-ng-class="{'class1': condition1, 'class2': condition2}">
</div>
```

Now if the use my directive as follows it throws up error

```
<my-custom-tag data-ng-class="{'class3': condition3}"></my-custom-tag>
```

The reason being, since the template also defines a `data-ng-class` attribute, the emitted HTML is as follows

```
<div data-ng-class="{'class3': condition3} {'class1': condition1, 'class2': condition2}"></div>
```

Hence the syntax error while compiling template. Any way to merge these objects ?

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HqUvxyxZ3vXKBOwVztSI?p=preview), look at the browser console for the error message and inspect element to check the `data-ng-class` attribute

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

I saw that there is a [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5695) talking about this.

You can use `compile` to modify the expression before the link function is triggered. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aqSoygsg5eVGpj3nvNub).

```
angular.module('directive', []).directive('myCustomTag', function() {
  return {
    template: "<div data-ng-class=\"{'foo': whenFoo()}\">My Custom Tag</div>",
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {

      tAttrs.ngClass = tAttrs.ngClass.replace(/}\s*{/g, ', ');

      return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        scope.whenFoo = function() {
          return true;
        };

      };
    }
  };
});
```