# Two ng-class on one element with compile is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, boolean-logic, ng-class

I scripted a directive which looks like this (I skip the unnecessary code) :

**Template**

```
<div ng-class="{'dir_a' : FoobarCtrl.dirFoo, 'dir_b' : !FoobarCtrl.dirFoo}" ng-transclude></div>
```

**Controller**

```
           return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: TemplateFileSeeAbove,
            scope: {},
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            controllerAs: 'FoobarCtrl',
            controller: controller,
            bindToController: {
                dirFoo: '@'
            },
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440194/merge-ngclass-attributes-when-replace-true
            compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) { // jshint ignore:line
                tAttrs.ngClass = tAttrs.ngClass.replace(/}\s*{/g, ', ');
            }
```

I use this to merge ng-class elements and in general it works perfectly

In my other template I use the directive with the following elements :

```
<test-directive ng-class="{'classA' : (varA || varB), 'classB' : (!(varA || varB))}">
random code
</test-directive>
```

even tho the compiled code looks file (I used console.log to check it) - it's somehow not working correctly.
If varA & varB are both TRUE my DIV gets both classes (classA & classB) - but it should only get the first one (classA).

The strange thing is if I replace

```
'classB' : (!(varA || varB))
```

into

```
'classB' : (!(true || true))
```

its working.
Anyone got an idea why it won't accept my $scope vars right ?

Thanks for any help ...

*edit*
It should be a problem with the compile function I am using here to merge two ng-class on the same element. When I remove the ng-class of my directive its working fine - might look like the directive can't get into touch with the scope vars.

Comment: In first template you're missing closing quote for `ng-class` attribute.

Comment: if what said jcubic is not this try varA==true || varB==true // varA!=true && varB != true

Comment: @jcubig - thanks was a type here - but its not missing in my real code

Comment: @Walfrat not working :(

Comment: Can you try 1st to move the ng-transclude in a sub div just in case ?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is :

```
<test-directive ng-class="{'classA' : ( {{varA}} || {{varB}} ), 'classB' : (!({{varA}} || {{varB}}))}">
random code
</test-directive>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.